# Did icarroussel enable 3D wheel like this?

Tags: icarousel

I have to present a menu like this in the picture :

[image]

where this buttons can move arround the cercle in the center similar to 3D effect, means you can see there dimensions transformation while moving.

I remember that iCarroussel project can do such things, Could Any pne guide me to the right control that provide this animation?

Thanks.

EDIT1 :

Ok I am able to see that iCarousel is almost what I need, but how to change the carousel vertical angle to get like the first picture? see how iCarousel is by default.

[image]

Comment: Why not use iCarousel if you think it can do what you need?

Comment: Which type of iCarrousel exactly?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) might be what you are looking for ;)

Comment: you can use iCarouselTypeRotary for displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is the following (Step by step as indicated below)

Download iCarousel ...

1. Open the sample project under Tests/ARC iOS (open iCarouselExample.xcodeproj)
2. Set default to "Cylinder" instead of "Coverflow" (in the viewDidLoad function of iCarouselExampleViewController.m)

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad 
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCylinder;
       navItem.title = @"Cylinder";
   }
   ```
3. Since you need just six items in your custom carousel set a "number of panes" in iCarouselExampleViewContoller.h as ...

   ```
   //NOTE! 
   #define NUMBER_OF_ITEMS 6
   ```
4. Use this NUMBER_OF_ITEMS to setup the carousel (i.e. in iCarouselExampleViewContoller.m change the setup function as follows (use 'wrap' as shown)

   ```
      - (void)setUp
   {
       //set up data
       wrap = YES;
       self.items = [NSMutableArray array];

       //NOTE! use preset number of vars in Carousel
       //for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
       for (int i=0; i< NUMBER_OF_ITEMS; i++)
       {
          [items addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
       }
   }
   ```
5. Now provide the perspective in iCarousel by updating the _perspective parameter in the uCarousel class. Do this in the setup function of iCarousel.m:

   ```
   - (void)setUp
   {
       _type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
       //NOTE! Tweak perspective parameters
       _perspective = -1.0f/750.0f; 
       ... etc ...
   }
   ```
6. Finally give the entire view a "tilt" about the X axis by rotating the carousel by 15 degrees about the x axis. The way to do this is to tweak the transform matrix  (set transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, -15.0f*M_PI/180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) In code, in the iCarousel.m's transformForItemView function update this as follows:

   ```
   - (CATransform3D)transformForItemView:(UIView *)view withOffset:(CGFloat)offset
   {   
   //set up base transform
       CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
       transform.m34 = _perspective;
       transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -_viewpointOffset.width, _viewpointOffset.height, 0.0f);

       //perform transform
       switch (_type)
       {
       .... SKIPPED THE INITIAL SECTIONS OF THIS CODE WE MAKE OUR CHANGE IN THE CYLINDER SECTION ... 
           case iCarouselTypeCylinder:
           case iCarouselTypeInvertedCylinder:
           {

           CGFloat count = [self circularCarouselItemCount];
           CGFloat spacing = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionSpacing withDefault:1.0f];
           CGFloat arc = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionArc withDefault:M_PI * 2.0f];
           CGFloat radius = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionRadius withDefault:fmaxf(0.01f, _itemWidth * spacing / 2.0f / tanf(arc/2.0f/count))];
           CGFloat angle = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionAngle withDefault:offset / count * arc];

           if (_type == iCarouselTypeInvertedCylinder)
           {
               radius = -radius;
               angle = -angle;
           }

           if (_vertical)
           {
               transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, 0.0f, -radius);
               transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
               return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, 0.0f, radius + 0.01f);
           }
           else
           {

               transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, 0.0f, -radius);

               //NOTE! Give it a tilt about the "X" axis
               transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, -15.0f*M_PI/180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

               transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

               return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, 0.0f, radius + 0.01f);
           }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this nice step by step.

Comment: You are welcome hafdeh! Your image looks very nice. I'd be interested in knowing what you use to model the individual 3D icon stations in your model. Is that with Google Sketchup?